# How do I import functions and class objects from another .sagews file in Cocalc?

Tags: python, file, sage

As an example of the kind of thing I'm trying to do, let's say I have a Cocalc project called TestProject.  I have a sagews file that contains definition and/or object classes.   Perhaps its called TestUtility and looks like this:

```
class TestClass():
    def __init__(self, number = 0):
        self.number = number
        self.square = number^2
        self.cube = number^3
        
def TestDef(n):
    return(n,n^2,n^3)
```

Now let's say I have another sagews file where I want to use this code.   Let's call it TestCalculations.  Perhaps I'd like to load stuff in from TestUtility and make use of it:

```
from TestUtility import*
TestNumber = TestDef(5)
TestClassObject = TestClass(3)
```

But, cocalc doesn't recognize this.  I'm not finding any good advice online for this.  I'm a mathematician first and a programmer second so I feel like I'm probably missing something that is obvious but I'm not sure how to find it.  Any thoughts?

I've tried a number of other things, like:

```
from TestUtility.sagews import*
from TestProject import*
from ~/ import*
from user import*
from home import*
```

I'm expecting to not get errors, and for a call of TestNumber to return (5,25,125) and TestClassObject to give me an object with properties: TestClassObject.square = 25, etc.

Comment: I've found the answer to my own question.  I'm leaving this here for anyone else asking something similar.  One should use attach("filename.sage") and the file being loaded should be .sage not .sagews